# timeseries of wind direction with dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

JS library: `dygraphs`

I need help in customizing the points in a time-series plot of wind-directions (x-axis: date, y-axis: direction). My wind direction values are from 0 to 359 degrees.

How to replace points in the time-series with arrows showing direction?

I do not know where to start, although I'm generally familiar with dygraphs. The closest example for my requirement is the figure show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912025/ggplot2-time-series-plot-with-colour-coded-wind-direction-arrows):

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following function will plot arrows on point locations.
Pass the function `quiver` to  `drawPointCallback` in options for the data series.

```
// cosmetic settings
var arrowheadlen = 10,
arrowbodylen = 30,
arrowheadangle = 0.4; // in radians between a head line and the man body line

// the series values range from 0 to 360 representing angles (outward flow direction)

  var quiver = function (g, series, ctx, cx, cy, color, radius, idx) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = 1
    var ang_vals = g.getValue(idx, 1) * (Math.PI / 180)
    var dx = arrowbodylen * Math.sin(ang_vals)
    var dy = arrowbodylen * Math.cos(ang_vals)

    // draw arrowline
    tox = cx + dx
    toy = cy - dy
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(cx, cy)
    ctx.lineTo(tox, toy)
    ctx.stroke()

    // draw arrowhead
    var lx = tox - arrowheadlen * Math.sin(ang_vals + arrowheadangle)
    var ly = toy + arrowheadlen * Math.cos(ang_vals + arrowheadangle)
    var rx = tox + arrowheadlen * Math.sin(arrowheadangle - ang_vals)
    var ry = toy + arrowheadlen * Math.cos(arrowheadangle - ang_vals)

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lx, ly);
    ctx.lineTo(tox, toy);
    ctx.lineTo(rx, ry);
    ctx.stroke();
};
```

Here is a sample output:
[image]